# 'guideline must specify type rc'

Tags: mfc

A small change on the *.rc file makes a problem with the project

Due to that I'm changing the Project.rc file and replacing that button to be the first one among all the other one.
My problem is that: It works as it expected to work, but due for that change it makes the project not to open the Resources View / Dialog
And it notifies me the following:
C:...ProjectName.rc (375)
Guideline must specify type
OK Edit Code
When I press the Edit code button on that Dialog it opens the Project.rc file but I can’t see any problem on that file at all.
I hope you could guide me regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

```
It turned out the rc file was somehow corrupted by VS2010 at some point. I had the original version in source control and re-merged them manually to fix it. The corrected code looks like this:

GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO
BEGIN
    IDD_ABOUTBOX, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 163
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 55
    END
END
```